# Calculate double limit with polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, limits, polar-coordinates

I have to calculate a double limit using polar coordintes. This is the limit:
    \begin{cases} 
  \frac{x|y|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2},} & (x,y)\neq (0,0),   
  \\ 0, & (x,y)=(0,0).
   \end{cases}

I tried to resolve myself but I can´t continune.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you convert the function you gave in Euclidian coordinates to one in polar coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you have to calculate the limit at $0$. It is likely to be zero since it is defined as $0$ at $0$.

Anyhow, rewriting in polar:

we take the limit $\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r\cos\theta * r|\sin\theta|}{r} = \lim_{r \to 0}(r\cos\theta*|\sin\theta|) = 0$

Comment: You do not have to have $\theta\to 0$. What if $\theta$ goes to $\pi/4$. You still have $x\to 0$ and $y\to 0$

Comment: Yeah true it is just a limit in r then